# Moment Generating Function for Brownian motion's exit of interval.

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, markov-process, moment-generating-functions

Let $B(t)$ be a standard BM. Consider the stopping time $T = \inf\{ t > 0: |B(t)| = a\},$ the usual first exit time of the interval $(-a, a).$

We can see that $\mathbb{E} e^{tT} < \infty$ for $t \in (0, \rho)$, for some positive $\rho$, by noticing $\mathbb{P}(T > n) \leq \mathbb{P}(T > n-1)\mathbb{P}(|B(n) - B(n-1)| \leq 2)$ and recursively stepping through $n$. We  also can see that $\rho$ can be taken to be $-\ln(\mathbb{P}(|B(t)| \leq 2))$.

Now we know from other theory that $\mathbb{E} e^{tT} = \frac{1}{\cosh(a\sqrt{-2t})}$ for $t <0.$ Is there a nice closed form for positive $t$ as well, since we know it's finite. Is the smallest such $\rho$ known?

Comment: Yes--unsurprisingly, for every positive $t<\pi^2/(8a^2)$, $$E(e^{tT})=1/\cos(a\sqrt{2t}),$$ and $E(e^{tT})=\infty$ for every $t\geqslant\pi^2/(8a^2)$. Note that this is the analytic continuation of the formula in your post.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! Is there a reference you know of with more details?

Comment: Probably quite a few books on Brownian motion by Marc Yor have it.

Comment: You do not by chance know where to find a proof for the closed form for $E(e^{tT})$?